# Why WEKA Evaluation class need train instances?

Tags: java, weka

I do not understand why Weka Evaluation class constructor needs the train instances to work.

can anybody explain me?

In theory, the evaluation depends only of the trained model (**cls** in the next code) and test data (**TestingSet**).

Thanks!

This is an example:

```
// TrainingSet is the training Instances

// TestingSet is the testingInstances

// Build de classifier

Classifier cls = (Classifier) new NaiveBayes();

cls.buildClassifier(TrainingSet);

// Test the model

Evaluation eTest = new Evaluation(**TrainingSet**); 

eTest.evaluateModel(cls, TestingSet);
```

Answer (score 0):

From [UMass Boston Computer Science Documentation on Weka](http://www.cs.umb.edu/~rickb/files/disc_proj/disc/weka/weka-3-2-3/doc/weka.classifiers.Evaluation.html#Evaluation(weka.core.Instances)) :

> **Evaluation
>   public Evaluation(Instances data) throws java.lang.Exception**
>
> Initializes all the counters for the evaluation.
>   **Parameters:**
>   data - set of training instances, to get some header information and prior class distribution information
>   **Throws:**
>   java.lang.Exception - if the class is not defined

You can take a look at the constructor source [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka/weka-stable/3.6.6/weka/classifiers/Evaluation.java#Evaluation.%3Cinit%3E%28weka.core.Instances%2Cweka.classifiers.CostMatrix%29).

Answer (score 0):

I have one posible solution to my own question. I was looking the way to evaluate a test file using a classifier model previously trained and saved in a file. The **Evaluation** class does not work for me because it needs the train data in the constructor. But it can be used the method **classifyInstance** of the classifier.

The next code is an example:

```
public static void LoadAndTest(String filename_test, String filename_model) throws Exception {
   BufferedReader datafile_test = readDataFile(filename_test);
   Instances      data_test     = new Instances(datafile_test);
   data_test.setClassIndex(data_test.numAttributes() - 1);

   Classifier cls = (Classifier) weka.core.SerializationHelper.read(filename_model);
   int act = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < data_test.numInstances(); i++) {
     double pred = cls.classifyInstance(data_test.instance(i));
     double real = data_test.instance(i).classValue();
     if (pred==real) {
       act = act + 1;
     }
   }  
   double pct = (double) act / (double) data_test.numInstances();
   System.out.println("Accuracy = " + pct);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ### For mapping results

Most of the algorithms work on numeric data. So all the `non-numeric` values of a feature have to converted into a numeric form. **This mapping has to be unique.** What this means is that all the values which have a specific non-numeric value will be mapped to the same numeric value.
While training the data, the data pre-processor sees the data for the very first time. While converting the non-numeric data the pre-processor uses `maps` to remember the mapping.
For e.g. If all possible values for a feature are {yes, no, maybe} then these values could be mapped like :
`{"yes":1, "no":2, "maybe":3}`
So, the input feature/column which looked like `[yes,yes,no,yes,maybe,yes]` would now be converted into an internal form of `[1,1,2,1,3,1]`. These numeric values are used by the algorithms.
Now this information is stored in Instances(trained) in Weka. So when the evaluator predicts a numeric value for a feature it needs to convert this numeric value to its actual value.
i.e. If the algo spits out a value of 2 it needs the map to figure out that 2 corresponds to 'no'. To do this the algorithm needs the mapping created before training. Hence it asks for training Instances.

`Note : AFAIK same logic applies in all ML frameworks like weka, dl4j, etc.`