# Incorrect class prediction using Weka

Tags: java, machine-learning, classification, weka, decision-tree

I am using the WEKA API *weka-stable-3.8.1*.
I have been trying to use [J48](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/trees/J48.html) decision tree(C4.5 implementation of weka).
My data has around 22 features and a nominal class with 2 possible values : *yes* or *no*.
While evaluating with the following code :

```
Classifier model = (Classifier) weka.core.SerializationHelper.read(trainedModelDestination);
Evaluation evaluation = new Evaluation(trainingInstances);
evaluation.evaluateModel(model, testingInstances);
System.out.println("Number of correct predictions : "+evaluation.correct());
```

I get **all predictions correct**.
But when I try these test cases individually using :

```
for(Instance i : testingInstances){
    double predictedClassLabel = model.classifyInstance(i);
    System.out.println("predictedClassLabel : "+predictedClassLabel);
}
```

I always get the same output, i.e. **0.0**.

Why is this happening ?

Comment: that's the predicted class label 0, maybe your testing instance only contain class label 0 and thus everything is correct.

Comment: Na, I tried with different test cases with known results.
Also tried instances from trained set.

Comment: May be your test instances are totally differents from train instances. Have you tried to evaluate your model on your train set?

Comment: Evaluation with training set gives 100% accuracy.

Comment: In this case, your model trained your dataset. May I ask how big is your training and test data?

Comment: 4000 instances in total : 1500 with class 'yes' and 2500 with class 'no'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should have updated much sooner.
Here's how I fixed this:

During the `training` phase, the model learns from your training set. While learning from this set it encounters [categorical/nominal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_variable) features as well.

Most algorithms require numerical values to work. To deal with this the algorithm maps the variables to a specific numerical value. [longer explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46418596/5051731)

Since the algorithm has learned this during the training phase, the `Instances` object holds this information. During `testing` phase you have to use the same `Instances` object that was created during `training` phase. Otherwise, the testing classifier will not correctly map your nominal values to their expected values.

Note:

> This kind of encoding gives [biased](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/9447/61897) training results in `Non-tree based models` and things like [One-Hot-Encoding](https://machinelearningmastery.com/why-one-hot-encode-data-in-machine-learning/) should be used in such cases.

Answer (score 0):

If the provided snippet is indeed from your code, you seem to be always classifying the first test instance: "testingInstances.firstInstance()".

Rather, you may want to make a loop to classify each test instance.

```
for(Instance i : testingInstances){
    double predictedClassLabel = model.classifyInstance(i);
    System.out.println("predictedClassLabel : "+predictedClassLabel);
}
```

Comment: Even after looping through all test cases, all results give an output of **0.0**. Problem is that no matter what the test case be : o/p is always **0.0**.

Comment: Modified the question for better explanation.